# What does 指命 mean?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

> 院長の指示通り動くのが我々の**指命**だ

They are two doctors talking together.

指命 is on Weblio, but not on Jisho. It seems like 指令, what's the difference between them though?

Comment: It's a typo for [使命](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%BF%E5%91%BD). 指命 seems to be a word listed in a dictionary, but it's so rare that I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Looking at the word 指命, I get the impression that it means "point (to someone) and appoint". 人を**指**して任**命**する. Of course that would not fit the context here

Answer (score 1):

I see a note from "naruto" that says, "It's a typo for 使命" ("mission").

Based on that, the sentence should translate into "Our mission is to act according to the director's instructions."

(I'm sorry if reiterating this isn't what should be done, as I am new and this is my second time answering a question here, and even this is based on a note from "naruto" and is not my original idea.  I just thought that it would be good to have this show up in the regular area for answers.)

Comment: I posted it as a comment because [it's a policy of this site](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1186/5010) to close questions based on simple typos.